# Where did the error "Could not initialize class javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer" come from?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I am making a game where the player can download the sound from the newground, this sound is downloaded in mp3 format. I added the Javazoom library to play this sound, but the code throws an error: "Could not initialize class javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer".

```
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer;

    @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
            try {
                player.open(new File(soundId+".mp3"));//soundId - id of the sound on newgrounds
                player.play();
            } catch (BasicPlayerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Help plis

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve] please.